# Load entire database with additional RAM?

Tags: mysql, memory, windows-server-2016, windows-sbs-2003

I recently upgraded my upgraded from Microsoft Small Business Server 2003 with 2 GB RAM, to a shiny-new server running Microsoft Windows Server 2016 with 64 GB RAM.  I configured MySQL on the server to use "all available memory" because that is the sole role of this server.  The total size of the single MySQL database is 20 GB, which represents roughly a third of the available RAM.

My question is:  Will the new server be able to read the entire 20 GB database from the SSD drive and load it into the 64 GB RAM?

I am expecting that the upgrade from 2 to 64 GB RAM will improve the speed of running database queries, but I am curious as to what type of improvements I should expect to see.

Comment: Why are you running MySQL on Windows?

Comment: Why not?  MySQL seems to work just fine for me on Windows.

Comment: It may work, but why pay for Windows to run Unix applications when you can just use Linux for free, and it is likely to work better there?  If you're going to pay for Windows, then why not pay for MS SQL, which is supported there and likely to work better?

Answer (score 0):

If your workload is read-centric, **and** if properly configured (ie: appropriate `innodb_buffer_pool_size`), **and** if you were disk-bound, you will probably have a tremendous performance boost.

With a catch: to bring data in memory, you *first* need to access them. This means that the first access to a row/record will be relatively slow, but successive accesses will be way faster. To bypass this phase, you could preload all data with some nightly SELECT queries (give a look [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/05/01/quickly-preloading-innodb-tables-in-the-buffer-pool/) for some example).

Comment: assuming all of his data tables (excluding system tables) are innodb tables this would work. set your buffer pool size to 40G and then as advised here, warm up your buffer pool by running select on all tables, you only have to do this once. then enable buffer pool dump on shutdown and buffer pool dump on startup so you won't have to warm up the buffer pool manually.